# Sinc to delta function: error term

Tags: distribution-theory

It is well known that

$$ \lim_{L\to\infty} \frac{\sin(L x)}{x} = \delta(x) $$

in the sense of distribution. Does anybody know of the error term in the above equation ? I am interested in the leading term $f_1(x)$ in an expansion of the form

$$ \frac{\sin(L x)}{x} = \delta(x) +\sum_{n=1} f_n (x)$$

where each $f_n(x)$ goes to zero faster than $f_m(x)$ ($n>m$) when $L\to \infty$.

It is quite easy to obtain the delta function identity using Fourier transform, as the Fourier transform of the sinc is the rect function (the indicator function of the set $[-L,L]$ (by the way, this is pretty much Ron's answer below). However when I try to obtain a series expansion I can't go beyond a tautology ($f_1(x) = \delta(x) - \sin(L x )/x$).

Comment: I think the question you should ask is, what is the error in assuming that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) \frac{\sin{L x}}{x} \approx f(0)$$

Comment: @RonGordon Absolutely. Isn't it in fact the same thing?

Comment: Sort of.  With integrals, though, you do not need to ask difficult questions about distributions.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use Parseval's theorem to express the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) \frac{\sin{L x}}{\pi x} = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-L}^L dk \, \hat{f}(k)$$

where

$$\hat{f}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) \, e^{i k x}$$
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, \hat{f}(k) \, e^{-i k x}$$
$$f(0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, \hat{f}(k) $$

Assume $f$ is even.  Then we may write

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x) \frac{\sin{L x}}{\pi x} = f(0) - \frac{2}{2 \pi} \int_L^{\infty} dk \, \hat{f}(k)$$

The error term for large $L$ then depends on the behavior of $\hat{f}$ for large values of $k$.  This in turn may depend on the continuity of the derivatives of $f$.

Comment: Thanks (why should I avoid posting "thanks"?), but this is exactly were I got stuck. Is it possible to go further?

Comment: The error term is now the integral of $\theta(k-L)$ times  $\hat{f}(k)$ (and some constants). Fourier transforming back the theta you get a tautology. One should make some expansion before this point.

PS I can't assume $f$ to be even.

Comment: @lcv: what can you assume about $f$?

Comment: @lcv: by the way, my last equation is a very general statement about the error.  Note that this error depends on $f$; I know of no better statement of the error term for a general $f$.

Comment: Doesn't also the leading term depend on $f$ ? :)

Comment: @lcv: of course.  But my point is, what more do you want without a further specification of $f$?

Comment: Well we can assume that $f$ is infinitely differentiable and decays faster than any (inverse) polynomial, i.e. $f\in\mathcal{S}$.